Not able to reproduce the security estimates in Kyber through leaky-LWE-estimator
Kyber has provided refined estimate for classical attacks in the Section 5.2 entitled "Beyond core-SVP hardness". Kyber utilized leaky-LWE-estimator https://github.com/lducas/leaky-LWE-Estimator/tree/NIST-round3 to obtain the the refined classical estimates. The results of the security analysis are summarized in Table 4 on page 21. I am attaching the screenshot for the reference.

As a part of my independent study on Kyber, I am trying to reproduce the result using leaky-LWE-estimator.. Unfortunately, the results I am obtaining through the github source code does not match with the results provided in the Table 4.
What am I missing? Has anybody tried to reproduce these refined classical estimates. Any help or suggestions towards addressing this problem is highly appreciated.

Supplementary materials
We ran the following script to estimate the refined classical estimates for KYBER768
load("../framework/instance_gen.sage")
n = 768
m = 768
q = 3329
D_s = build_centered_binomial_law(2)
D_e = build_centered_binomial_law(2)
A, b, dbdd = initialize_from_LWE_instance(DBDD, n, q, m, D_e, D_s)
# In such parameter range, no need to integrate q-vectors
beta, delta = dbdd.estimate_attack()

We obtained the following output
      Build DBDD from LWE      
 n=768   m=768   q=3329 
       Attack Estimation      
 dim=1537    δ=1.002899      β=624.97  

As we can note from the above mentioned data, we obtain a block size of 624.97, whereas official documentation of Kyber reports a block size of 637. Moreover, the lattice attack dimension are also not matching. We got dimension as 1537, while Kyber reports 1467.

Updates on July 20, 2024
We also tried to run the lightweight version available on Github repo.
load("../framework/instance_gen.sage")

verbosity = 2
report_every = None

# Kyber-512 round 2 parameters
n = 768
m = 768
q = 3329
D_s = build_centered_binomial_law(2)
D_e = D_s

_, _, inst = initialize_from_LWE_instance(DBDD_predict_diag, n, q,
                                          m, D_e, D_s, verbosity=verbosity)

inst.integrate_q_vectors(q)
inst.estimate_attack()
print(" Attack Estimation via simulation + probabilistic model ")

inst.estimate_attack(probabilistic=True, lift_union_bound=True, silent=False)

We obtained the following results
integrate short vector hint   3329*c1466 ∈ Λ     Worthy hint !   dim=1467, δ=1.00290414, β=623.41 
 integrate short vector hint   3329*c1465 ∈ Λ        Unworthy hint, Rejected. 
       Attack Estimation      
 ln(dvol)=5661.0782118   ln(Bvol)=5661.0782118   ln(Svol)=0.0000000     δ(β)=1.002904 
 dim=1467    δ=1.002904      β=623.41  
  
 Attack Estimation via simulation + probabilistic model 
β= 2,    pr=0.0000e+00,      cum-pr=0.0000e+00   rem-pr=1.0000e+00
β= 3,    pr=0.0000e+00,      cum-pr=0.0000e+00   rem-pr=1.0000e+00


KeyError: 1027

Now, we are obtaining the same lattice attack dimension as mentioned in Table 4, but still, the results of block size are not matching with the results mentioned in Table 4 of Kyber official documentation.

The code from your update (July 20, 2024) is essentially that of kyber-bkz.sage script from the leaky-LWE repo (NIST-round3) branch. It currently crashes (KeyError: 1027), so the result you are waiting for is not displayed.
The β=623.41 you see appearing is displayed by the call to
inst.estimate_attack(), which does not use refine estimation. The refine estimation is what inst.estimate_attack(probabilistic=True, lift_union_bound=True, silent=False) is supposed to provide but crashes on your machine.
It seems to be running fine on my machine (it is currently trying β=150, while yours crashed at β=3). I'll let it run to the end for confirmation and will update my message (might take a few hours). But I think this is more a issue of code and installation than a crypto question: I invite you to move this discussion to the github bugtracker https://github.com/lducas/leaky-LWE-Estimator/issues .
Update
The calculation finished, and both your code and the one from kyber-bkz.sage returned β=637.43 as the refined estimate (simulation + probabilistic model).
       Attack Estimation      
 ln(dvol)=5661.0782118   ln(Bvol)=5661.0782118   ln(Svol)=0.0000000     δ(β)=1.002904 
 dim=1467    δ=1.002904      β=623.41  
  
(623.4081744337865, 1.00290413632411)
 Attack Estimation via simulation + probabilistic model 
β= 622,  pr=7.5229e-05,      cum-pr=1.3682e-04       rem-pr=9.9986e-01
β= 623,  pr=1.5812e-04,      cum-pr=2.9492e-04   rem-pr=9.9971e-01
β= 624,  pr=3.2203e-04,      cum-pr=6.1685e-04   rem-pr=9.9938e-01
β= 625,  pr=6.3536e-04,      cum-pr=1.2518e-03   rem-pr=9.9875e-01
β= 626,  pr=1.2143e-03,      cum-pr=2.4646e-03   rem-pr=9.9754e-01
β= 627,  pr=2.2478e-03,      cum-pr=4.7069e-03   rem-pr=9.9529e-01
β= 628,  pr=4.0300e-03,      cum-pr=8.7180e-03   rem-pr=9.9128e-01
β= 629,  pr=6.9973e-03,      cum-pr=1.5654e-02   rem-pr=9.8435e-01
β= 630,  pr=1.1766e-02,      cum-pr=2.7236e-02   rem-pr=9.7276e-01
β= 631,  pr=1.9161e-02,      cum-pr=4.5876e-02   rem-pr=9.5412e-01
β= 632,  pr=3.0225e-02,      cum-pr=7.4714e-02   rem-pr=9.2529e-01
β= 633,  pr=4.6183e-02,      cum-pr=1.1745e-01   rem-pr=8.8255e-01
β= 634,  pr=6.8376e-02,      cum-pr=1.7779e-01   rem-pr=8.2221e-01
β= 635,  pr=9.8114e-02,      cum-pr=2.5846e-01   rem-pr=7.4154e-01
β= 636,  pr=1.3650e-01,      cum-pr=3.5969e-01   rem-pr=6.4031e-01
β= 637,  pr=1.8423e-01,      cum-pr=4.7765e-01   rem-pr=5.2235e-01
β= 638,  pr=2.4135e-01,      cum-pr=6.0372e-01   rem-pr=3.9628e-01
β= 639,  pr=3.0713e-01,      cum-pr=7.2543e-01   rem-pr=2.7457e-01
β= 640,  pr=3.8002e-01,      cum-pr=8.2977e-01   rem-pr=1.7023e-01
β= 641,  pr=4.5768e-01,      cum-pr=9.0768e-01   rem-pr=9.2319e-02
β= 642,  pr=5.3723e-01,      cum-pr=9.5728e-01   rem-pr=4.2723e-02
β= 643,  pr=6.1554e-01,      cum-pr=9.8357e-01   rem-pr=1.6425e-02
β= 644,  pr=6.8960e-01,      cum-pr=9.9490e-01   rem-pr=5.0983e-03
β= 645,  pr=7.5686e-01,      cum-pr=9.9876e-01   rem-pr=1.2396e-03
β= 646,  pr=8.1550e-01,      cum-pr=9.9977e-01   rem-pr=2.2870e-04
       Attack Estimation      
 ln(dvol)=5661.0782118   ln(Bvol)=5661.0782118   ln(Svol)=0.0000000     δ(β)=1.002857 
 dim=1467            β=637.43  
  
(637.426072334414, None)


We have tried running the script in three different systems with both ubuntu and windows os. We tried the sage version 10.3 installed inside Anaconda and also binary version sage 9.3 in windows.  All of them gives the same error as mentioned in the post. It would be helpful if you can please share the specification of the system and installation method of sage.

Updates: We found out that we were running the wrong branch. Issue is resolved now. Thank you very much for your time on this issue. Have a great day ahead!!
